# checking undefined objects while populating object

Tags: javascript

I have an object "response", and I want to populate another object "user" with response's content, like this :

```
var  userr = {
            _id: new Date().toISOString()
            , authVia: "FB"
            , email: response.email
            , firstName: response.first_name
            , lastName: response.last_name
            , gender: response.gender
            , hometown: response.hometown.name
            , fbId: response.id
            , locale: response.locale
            , location: response.location.name
            , timezone: response.timezone
            , fbVerified: response.verified
        };
```

but sometimes response.hometown is undefined, and the code stops without any errors in the log console.
How can I check it every object is defined in a simple manner before or while populating "user" ? Is it possible to insert "if" in the object ?

Thanks

Comment: Kind of: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use:

```
hometown: response.hometown && response.hometown.name,
```

and similar for other elements. If `response.hometown` is not defined, the short-circuiting of `&&` will prevent the attempt to evaluate `response.hometown.name`, so you won't get an error.

Comment: What if response hometown is deliberately set to an empty string? that's falsy

Comment: You can't get the `name` property of an empty string.

Comment: or you can use  hometown:response.hometown || second value that should be given to response.hometown if it doesn't exist  example hometown : response.hometown || 'some string'

Comment: @hamism If you use `||`, it will never read the `.name` property.

Comment: sorry i mean hometown = response.hometown.name || 'some value otherwise'

Comment: Sorry Bamrar, hometown was a bad example. But what about email (as in my answer?) what if its acceptable for it to be an empty string but OP said (s)he wanted to check for undefined, only one of several falsy values as you undoubtedly know. Logical shortcircuiting is short and elegant and we all use it, but if you really want to know if a property exists on an object its `hasOwnProperty()` or `foo.bar === undefined`

Comment: @JaredSmith That's a different question. The question is specifically about the cases that cause Javascript errors due to trying to access a property of `undefined`. He's not asking about providing a default value for properties being copied.

Comment: @hamism That won't work because it will get an error trying to access the `name` property of `undefined`.

Comment: Sorry Bamrar got it from your comment on my answer. You are correct. Changed my IIFE.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Can you provide a general solution, including for the other variables (the others lines of my code) ?

Comment: @Louis They should all be similar: `x.y && x.y.z`. If you have to go more levels, it's `a.b && a.b.c && a.b.c.d && a.b.c.d.e ...`

Comment: @Barmar I am going to try this. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

If you have some default value, you could use the ternary operator.

```
var userr = {
    ...
    , hometown: response.hometown ? response.hometown.name : "N/A"
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable

```
hometownName = typeof response.hometown == "undefined" ? "something" : response.hometown.name;
```

And inside userr

```
, hometown: hometownName
```